# How to call wx.Frame from a class when I am not using the super function?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

```
class A(object): 
    def routine(self):
        print "A.routine()"
class B(A):
    def routine(self):
        print "B.routine()"
        A().routine()
def fun():
    b = B()
    b.routine()
if __name__ == '__main__':fun()
```

When I use the above code the A().routine executes the command in method of class A but when I use the code:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, title):

    wx.Frame().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 200))
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Size')
    app.MainLoop()
```

why is it that

```
wx.Frame().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 200))
```

does not work similar to

```
A().routine()
```

and instead shows the error:
TypeError: Required argument 'parent' {pos 1} not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
A().routine()
```

creates a *new* `A` object and calls the method on *that* object.

To call the base class method for your own object, use this:

```
super(B, self).routine()
```

For your example frame, use:

```
class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(300, 200))
        ...
```

---

If you really do not want to use `super`, call the base class method explicitly:

```
class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(300, 200))
        ...
```

---

See also [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods).

Comment: Is it possible to do the same without using the super command? Using super I was getting the result even earlier. What I am looking for here is an alternative by directly using wx.Frame() method

Comment: See the link at the bottom.

Comment: Again the question comes back to level 0. As my original question says I do not want to use the super function. Is there any alternative by directly using wx.Frame() method? If yes could you please post the solution code to my problem?

Comment: No, there is no solution that uses the  `wx.Frame()` method. You must use the `wx.Frame` class instead.